# Helm rollback to previous release

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am looking for a way to rollback a helm release to its previous release without specifying the target release version as a number.

Something like `helm rollback <RELEASE> ~1` (like `git reset HEAD~1`)  would be nice.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Unlike the previous old answers above.

**According to the latest [documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_rollback/)**, you can **rollback to the previous version by simply omitting the  argument** in `helm rollback`. Which means your command should like below to rollback to the previous version.

`helm rollback <RELEASE_NAME>`

But if you need to rollback to specific previous version, You can:

**First:** List revision numbers by running `helm history <RELEASE_NAME>`

**Second:** Roll back to the version you want using `helm rollback <RELEASE> [REVISION]`

Answer (score 62):

As it turns out, there is an undocumented option to rollback to the previous release by defining the target release version as 0.
like: `helm rollback <RELEASE> 0`

Source: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1796

Comment: this command seems to rollback to previous revision regardless of it being successful or not.

Comment: The official doc says:  The first argument of the rollback command is the name of a release, and the second is a revision (version) number. If this argument is omitted, it will roll back to the previous release. The 0 is no long required. https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_rollback/

Comment: "Error: release: not found"

Answer (score 18):

If you just want to rollback to the previous release, you can do

```
helm rollback <RELEASE> 0
```

Answer (score 12):

Using **Helm**

`helm rollback release-name 0`

Using **kubectl**

What does rollout/rollback in kubectl means?
Rolling updates allow the following actions:

1. Promote an application from one environment to another (via container image updates).
2. Rollback to previous versions.
3. Continuous Integration and Continuous Delivery of applications with zero downtime.

`kubectl rollout undo deployment/deployment-name`

**or**

`kubectl rollout undo deployment/deployment-name --to-revision=0`

Comment: Please note that `kubectl` this way will rollback only the deployment, but not other resources associated with helm release.

Comment: @aleksandr erokhin yes that's absolutely true, because kubectl maintains only the Deployment object and helm maintains the release which contains all the manifest/objects altogether. I have updated the answer however the above was just a way to provide how does it work in kubectl.

Answer (score 7):

Below are the steps you can rollback Using Helm:

1. Check the name of a release and (version) number using `$ helm ls`
2. The first argument of the rollback command is the name of a release, and the second is a revision (version) number.

```
$ helm rollback RELEASE [REVISION]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do -

```
helm rollback <release-name> <release version> -n <namespace>
```

In helm3 namespace is required, whereas in lower version, you can do below -

```
helm rollback <release-name> <release version>
```