# How to rollback data when perform release rollback from prod?

Tags: kubernetes, release, kubernetes-helm, rollback

From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59558640/10894456 the rollback could be performed by:

Using **Helm**

`helm rollback release-name 0`

Using **kubectl**

`kubectl rollout undo deployment/deployment-name`

**or**

`kubectl rollout undo deployment/deployment-name --to-revision=0`

My question is: how to also rollback data which was involved while failed release has been working on prod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see only two options:

- Application is data-aware so after rollback, it will delete/revert data
- Restore data from snapshot/backup

Comment: in case of 2nd option, is it possible to automatize it?

Comment: Yes, but it strongly depends on your stack. It will be much easier on cloud providers than on bare-metal k8s.